# Looping over a list, checking a boolean and return value

Tags: java

There are a number of different ways to do this. What do people prefer and why?

```
public boolean checkNameStartsWith(List<Foo> foos) {
    for (Foo foo : foos) {
        if (!(foo.getName().startsWith("bar"))) {
            return Boolean.FALSE;
        }
    }
    return Boolean.TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

I'd change `Boolean.FALSE` to `false` and `Boolean.TRUE` to `true`. Using the constants objects from `Boolean` is rather unnecessary since the method returns with primitive `boolean`.

Comment: I had got into the habit of always referencing the static constants as consumes less memory. Other people don't then ?

Comment: a reference to an object consuming less memory then a primitive? Do you have tests verifying that? Even if it is true, did you actually encounter a case where it did matter?

Comment: @NimChimpsky: Using `Boolean.FALSE` and `TRUE` is better than creating new objects with `new Boolean(false)` but here the return type is `boolean` primitive, not an object reference.

Comment: @JensSchauder a reference to lots and lots of primitives across my whole application, consumes less memory than one Object reference, was my thinking.

Comment: there are no references to primitives. Just references or primitives. In case of a local boolean the difference surely is neglectable. If you have huge volumes of those (like huge Arrays) one should do some tests. For everything else, use the one easiest on the eye.

Answer (score 8):

Though `for` loop is enough, you can rewrite using [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v13.0.1/javadoc/src-html/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#line.628) if you like lambdas:

```
public boolean checkNameStartsWith(List<Foo> foos){
    return Iterables.all(foos, new Predicate<Foo>() {
        public boolean apply(Foo foo) {
            return foo.getName().startsWith("bar");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the other answers, I suggest adding a second parameter to the `checkNameStartsWith` method named `prefix`, e.g.

```
public boolean checkNameStartsWith(List<Foo> foos, final String prefix) {
    for (Foo foo : foos) {
        if (!foo.getName().startsWith(prefix)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I know it [probably doesn't matter from a performance standpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887769/java-loop-efficiency-if-continue-or-if) (due to branch prediction and compiler optimization), but I still prefer this form:

```
public boolean checkNameStartsWith(List<Foo> foos) {
    for (Foo foo : foos) {
        if (foo.getName().startsWith("bar")) continue;

        // Mismatch found
        return false; 
    }
    return true;
}
```

I think it's because it makes it easier to see that you're absolutely done with the iteration once you've determined there's no match.  Otherwise, you might have something like this:

```
public boolean myMethod(List<Foo> foos, final String prefix) {
    for (Foo foo : foos) {
        if (!foo.getName().startsWith(prefix)) {
            // do something complex (many lines of code)
        }
        // here you could possibly do something else, regardless of condition true/false
    }
    return true;
}
```

You don't know unless you search for the end of the loop whether something is still done if the condition is false.

Answer (score 1):

`Boolean.FALSE` and `Boolean.TRUE` should be definitely replaced with `true` and `false` because of auto-boxing. You don't need an additional `Integer.intValue()` call for each  invocation.

I'm pretty sure Oracle HotSpot will optimize this automatically, but the code readability still suffers.

Answer (score 0):

Have only one exit point from the method. Also, despite being old school, I would iterate using a while loop with a stop condition instead of the for-each.

```
public boolean checkNamesStartWith(List<Foo> foos, String prefix) {
  boolean ret = true;
  int index = 0;
  while (index < foos.size() && ret) {
    ret &= foos.get(index).getName().startsWith(prefix);
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Here the while loop will only iterate as long as it doesn't find a foo that starts with the prefix - or will iterate through the whole list. I would also rename the method from `checkNameStart` to `checkNamesStart` as it iterates through a whole collection, so usually more than one names will be checked.

Or, to preserve readibility, you can use an if condition with a break from the for-each loop:

```
public boolean checkNamesStartWith(List<Foo> foos, String prefix) {
  boolean ret = true;
  for (Foo foo : foos) {
    if (!foo.getName().startsWith(prefix)) {
      ret = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would actually suggest you making a number of improvements:

1) Use an Iterator to walk over the list. Although this solution does not provide any performance benefits over the for loop, it actually makes your code more generalized and easier adaptable, should you sometime decide to use some other collection instead of a List.

2) Replace `Boolean.TRUE` and `BOOLEAN.FALSE` stuff by `true` and `false` respectively for reasons, explained by **stoweesh**.

3) Get rid of multiple returns. When you find an element in the list whose name does not start with bar, just set a boolean variable and break out of the loop. Return only in the end. This also improves readability and maintainability of your code.

My version of the iteration looks like this:

```
 public boolean checkNameStartsWith(List<Foo> foos) {

        Iterator<Foo> it = foos.iterator();
        boolean isAllStartWithBar = true;

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            if (!it.next().getName().startsWith("bar")) {
                isAllStartWithBar = false;
                break;
            }            
        }

        return isAllStartWithBar;   
    }
```

Comment: `it actually makes your code more generalized and easier adaptable` really? foreach loop supports arrays, but your approach cannot be adopted to arrays. Also, I'd recommend use an iterator instead of foreach only if you need to remove elements.

Comment: @tcb well, he did not say anything about arrays anyway, code features a List. And iterators are usable with arrays, just transform array into List by calling Arrays.asList. By more generalized I mean easier to adopt, if you decide to change the data structure, say use a LinkedList, ArrayList, some custom collection, etc. instead of List making your code polimorphic. Iterator enables you not only safely remove elements from the collection, but also supports paralelly traversing multiple collections, if you need. For these reasons I generally prefer to use an iterator rather than a foor loop.